# dynamic base url using nextjs 13 server component

Tags: next.js

while trying the new next app folder, which by default all components are generated on the server. I couldn't find a way to get the baseUrl to call nextjs internal api (pages/api).

since it's on the server there is not window object to get url and you cannot use react Hooks.

If I'd use a client component using app folder i'd be able to fetch using the old next convention ( fetch("api") ). but I will not be able to use features like generateStaticParams to generate all static pages.

only work around I could think of is writing out the url's manually or using env variables. but will need to configure for each environment.

has anyone found a dynamic way?